# setFont not Working as Expected

Tags: ios, objective-c

My question is more a curiosity

I'm trying to make my application be responsive when the user changes the size of the iOS font.

To do it, I've put the following observer in the `viewWillAppear` function:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver : self selector : @selector(refreshTextFontSize:) name : UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object : nil];
```

in my ViewController.

And my refreshTextFontSize function is like this:

```
- (void) refreshTextFontSize : (NSNotification*)notification
{
    [[self textView] setFont : [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]];
}
```

(My view is a view with only a TextView inside, which outlet name is textView)

**This is not working.**

When the app is running and I change the iOS font size on the iPhone settings, nothing happens in my app.

But, if I manually call the `refreshTextFontSize` function inside the `viewWillAppear` **everything works**. When the app is initialized, it comes with the correct font size and when I change the font size on settings with the app opened it also responds very well.

So, my question is: Why I have to call the `refreshTextFontSize` function inside `viewWillAppear` to make my app responds to user changes on the iOS font size when my app is **already open**? I can't see why I have to add that last line of code to make my app changes the font size when it is already opened, since the `refreshTextFontSize` function is automatically called. The `refreshTextFontSize` is, in fact, being called by the observer every time I change the iOS font size. However, it does not work if I don't have that last line of code.

Not sure if I explained clearly, but any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I could be incorrect but I think it has to do with the fact that iOS apps don't run in the background. Sure your app is open in the background, but it will not run any code. There are some permissions you can ask for, but off hand I don't think any apply to changing the font. Your best bet is sign up for the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification and change the font then.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Although the wordings a bit confusing, I agree with this answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are correct, the app does not execute any code in background. However, I've checked and my app was running the `refreshTextFontSize` every time the user changed the font size on the iOS settings and, also, put the app in foreground. So, even though no code runs when the app is in background, the correct function is being called when the app returns to the screen. What is weird is that the function only works if I add the last line of code